# create lag features based on multiple columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

i have a time series dataset. i need to extract the lag features. i am using below code but got all NAN's

```
df.groupby(['week','id1','id2','id3'],as_index=False)['value'].shift(1)
```

input

```
week,id1,id2,id3,value
1,101,123,001,45
1,102,231,004,89
1,203,435,099,65
2,101,123,001,48
2,102,231,004,75
2,203,435,099,90
```

output

```
week,id1,id2,id3,value,t-1
1,101,123,001,45,NAN
1,102,231,004,89,NAN
1,203,435,099,65,NAN
2,101,123,001,48,45
2,102,231,004,75,89
2,203,435,099,90,65
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to shift to the next week so remove `'week'` from the grouping:

```
df['t-1'] = df.groupby(['id1','id2','id3'],as_index=False)['value'].shift()
#    week  id1  id2  id3  value   t-1
#0     1  101  123    1     45   NaN
#1     1  102  231    4     89   NaN
#2     1  203  435   99     65   NaN
#3     2  101  123    1     48  45.0
#4     2  102  231    4     75  89.0
#5     2  203  435   99     90  65.0
```

---

That's error prone to missing weeks. In this case we can merge after changing the week, which ensures it is the prior week regardless of missing weeks.

```
df2 = df.assign(week=df.week+1).rename(columns={'value': 't-1'})
df = df.merge(df2, on=['week', 'id1', 'id2', 'id3'], how='left')
```

---

Another way to bring and rename many columns would be to use the `suffixes` argument in the merge. This will rename all overlapping columns (that are not keys) in the right DataFrame.

```
df.merge(df.assign(week=df.week+1),         # Manally lag
         on=['week', 'id1', 'id2', 'id3'], 
         how='left',
         suffixes=['', '_lagged']           # Right df columns -> _lagged
         )
#   week  id1  id2  id3  value  value_lagged
#0     1  101  123    1     45           NaN
#1     1  102  231    4     89           NaN
#2     1  203  435   99     65           NaN
#3     2  101  123    1     48          45.0
#4     2  102  231    4     75          89.0
#5     2  203  435   99     90          65.0
```

Comment: May I ask if I have multiple value columns to shift say `value1, value2. etc`, how can I apply your method?

Comment: @ahbon The merge will by default bring all of the columns, so it should work without really changing anything. I added a section to illustrate how you go about redoing this so that it renames all of the columns, which uses the `suffixes` argument of `DataFrame.merge`