# Creating lagged variable

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a lagged variable of `Total_Damages`.

```
   `Company_name` Year      Total_Damages ROA
   `ABC`          1996      1111          `2`
   `ABC`          1998      2422          `2`
   `ABC`          1999      3232          `9`
   `ASD`          1996      2132          `1`
   `ASD           1997      3444          `12`
   `ASD`          1998      200           `1`
   `ASD`          1999      1987          `12`
```

All variables need to be shifted to a year later. The ideal result would look like:

```
Year   `Total_Damages` ROA
1996   `Nan`           `2`
1997   `1111`          `Nan`
1998   `Nan`           `2`
1999   `2422`          `Nan`
1999   `Nan`           `9`
2000   `3232`          `Nan`
1996   `Nan`           `1`
1997   `2132`          `Nan`
1997   `Nan`           `12`
1998   `3444`          `Nan`
1998   `Nan`           `1`
1999   `200`           `Nan`
1999   `Nan`           `12`
2000   `1987`          `Nan`
```

I used this code, but it did not provide the desired result:

```
df.loc[:,'Total_Damages_lag'] = df.groupby('Year')['Total_damages'].shift(1)
```

In addition, I used the following code, which did work. However, my dataframe then turned into a list. If I convert it back, the majority of the rows are deleted.

```
grouped_df = df.groupby(df['company_name'])


def lag_by_group(key, value_df):
    df = value_df.assign(company_name = key)
    return (df.sort_values(by=["Year"], ascending=True).set_index(["Year"]).shift(1))

df = [lag_by_group(g, grouped_df.get_group(g)) for g in grouped_df.groups.keys()]
pd.concat(df, axis=0)
```

How can I either lag my variable in a different way or fix my list problem?

Comment: Your expected output is exactly the same as the input. Just add 1 to the year or shift the index by 1. I don't follow the calculations

Comment: Your input is very confusing, because dates are repeated. However, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58295815/create-lag-features-based-on-multiple-columns should answer your question if there aren't repeats (or there is another column which distinguishes between repeats). Just merge with itself after modifying the year

Comment: Now your expected output doesn't make sense. Why would you want that?

Comment: My apologies. I edited my post. Hopefully this clears things up.

Comment: @roganjosh I have two variables, namely ROA and Total_damages. I only need to lag Total_damages. I assumed that the result would look like that.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that output? It's just strange that such a table would ever be a *desired* output, or useful in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
df.year=df.year+1
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to just create two copies of the dataframe, and essentially create the "lagged" format by hand.

Note that it is much easier to answer such questions if you provide a way to create the dataframe itself in the question. I have added a sample of first three rows.

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np
temp = {'Company_name': ['ABC']*3,
        'Year': [1996, 1998, 1999],
        'Total_Damages': [1111, 2422, 3232],
        'ROA': [2, 2, 9]}

df = pd.DataFrame(temp)

df1 = df.copy()
df2 = df.copy()
print(df)
#Output:
  Company_name  Year  Total_Damages  ROA
0          ABC  1996           1111    2
1          ABC  1998           2422    2
2          ABC  1999           3232    9
```

Now, for the top half, we just set the Total_Damages to null, as they will be "lagged" by 1 year.

```
df1['Total_Damages'] = pd.np.nan
print(df1)
#Output:
  Company_name  Year  Total_Damages  ROA
0          ABC  1996            NaN    2
1          ABC  1998            NaN    2
2          ABC  1999            NaN    9
```

As for the bottom half, we increment the year, and set the non lagged columns to null (ROA in this case)

```
df2['Year'] += 1
df2['ROA'] = pd.np.nan
print(df2)
#Output:
  Company_name  Year  Total_Damages  ROA
0          ABC  1997           1111  NaN
1          ABC  1999           2422  NaN
2          ABC  2000           3232  NaN
```

Finally, join the dataframes together, and sort on indexes to get the correct rows next to each other.

```
out = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
print(out)
#Output:
  Company_name  Year  Total_Damages  ROA
0          ABC  1996            NaN  2.0
1          ABC  1997         1111.0  NaN
2          ABC  1998            NaN  2.0
3          ABC  1999         2422.0  NaN
4          ABC  1999            NaN  9.0
5          ABC  2000         3232.0  NaN
```