# How to determine if a value in a pandas dataframe also exists for a previous date?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that tracks values for several thousand properties on a weekly basis. The value is logged every Sunday. I am trying to set a flag on each entry of the data frame if the property was logged exactly 52 weeks ago (i.e. we've been tracking the property for at least a year).

```
report['Flag A'] =0
Weeks = report['Survey Date'].unique()

for week in Weeks:
    current_props = report.loc[report['Survey Date'] == week]['PropertyId'].unique()
    previous_year_props = report.loc[report['Survey Date'] == pd.to_datetime(week) - pd.DateOffset(weeks = 52)]['PropertyId'].unique()

    for prop in current_props:
        if prop in previous_year_props:
            report.loc[((report['RAOT Week'] == week) & (report['PropertyId'] == prop)), 'Flag A'] = 1
```

From what I can tell, the code works exactly as intended. However, it's been running for ten minutes now and seems to have only gotten through 1/10th of the data frame. Is there a more straightforward/less resource intensive way to accomplish this?

Comment: Soemthing like the merge solution of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58295815/create-lag-features-based-on-multiple-columns/58295870#58295870. Copy the `df`, add 52 weeks to your date, then left merge that with your original DataFrame on all the matching columns and date and if the resulting merged value is `notnull` you can create your flag for it existing

Comment: I'll give this a try!

Comment: Can also just use the `indicator` argument and just map `'left_only'` and `'both'` to False/True, instead of bringing along other data

Comment: Delayed response, but just wanted to say that this solution worked perfectly, thank you!